# Scala's List unpacking

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So my problem is simple. I have come across this many times, and my brain is unable to find a solution.

How can I unpack a list into another list, for an indefinite amount of variables?

Here is what I mean.

```scala
val list1 = List(List(7, 4), List(7, 6))

val list2 = List(List(1), List(5), List(8))

val desired_list1 = List(List(1, 7, 4), List(5, 7, 4), List(8, 7, 4))

val desired_list2 = List(List(1, 7, 6), List(5, 7, 6), List(8, 7, 6))

//** The desired_list1 and 2 must be a List[List[Int]] it cannot be List[List[Any]] 

//Here's my attempt, which oddly enough completely ignores all elements of list1(0) which are not the first(7).

val attempt = list2.map(i => i +: list1(0)).map(j => j.collect{ case k:Int => k; case l @ a :: b => a}).map(m => m.map{ case i:Any => i.toString.toInt})

//The result is 

attempt: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 7), List(5, 7), List(8, 7))

//while it should be:

val desired_list1 = List(List(1, 7, 4), List(5, 7, 4), List(8, 7, 4))
```

I need a way to unpack that is not manual, please do not tell me to do this:

```scala
val attempt = list2.map(k => k +: list1(0)).map{ case (k, List(x, y)) => (k, x, y)}
```

Basically, list1 could have any number of elements. e.g

```scala
val list1 = List(List(99, 83, 2, 3, 4), List(99, 83, 2, 5 7))
```

However, these numbers are never repeated, so I guess it could be a set as well. But I don't know much about sets or if it'd help in any way.

Comment: Isn't it just `val desired_list1 = list2.map(k => k +: list1(0))`, no second `map` required?

Comment: No because then it'll become `List(List(1, List(7, 4))` for instance

Comment: No, it won't, try it: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/aBvAKMR/1. Of course, your current edit makes it different, use `++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```
val lists: List[List[Int]] = List(List(7, 4), List(7, 6))    
val prefixes: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(5), List(8))

val res: List[List[Int]] = for{
  prefix <- prefixes.flatten
  rest <- lists
} yield prefix :: res

// res: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 7, 4), List(1, 7, 6), List(5, 7, 4), List(5, 7, 6), List(8, 7, 4), List(8, 7, 6))
```

Unless, you actually want a list that contains your `desired_list1` and `desired_list2` together, in which case you need:

```
val res3 = lists.map{ rest => 
  prefixes.flatten.map{prefix =>
    prefix :: rest
  }
}

/// res3: List[List[List[Int]]] =
// List(
//  List(
//      List(1, 7, 4), List(5, 7, 4), List(8, 7, 4)
//  ), 
//  List(
//      List(1, 7, 6), List(5, 7, 6), List(8, 7, 6)
//  )
// )
```

Comment: Thanks!. Would this work in a distributed manner? e.g with Spark and RDD's?

Comment: That is a completely different problem and I am not sure I have enough data to give you a valid answer for it.

Comment: Thanks anyways. I forgot to add that actually list2 should be: `val list2 = List(List(1), List(5), List(8))`

Comment: that just needs a `.flatten`. Updated the answer. If that answers your question, mark it answered, pls. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly why you would want that but try this out:

```
val list1 = List(List(7, 4), List(7, 6))
val list2 = List(1, 5, 8)

list2.flatMap(element=> list1.map(innerList=> element:: innerList))
```

output: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 7, 4), List(1, 7, 6), List(5, 7, 4), List(5, 7, 6), List(8, 7, 4), List(8, 7, 6))

Comment: Estou a desenvolver um novo algoritmo para achar as minimal transversals de um hypergraph, e isto faz parte do mesmo.